# How to Select ABS(Value) when a condition is being met in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, absolute-value

- When an Account is 'PrePaid' (PlanCode = P0100) then the balance owing is in negative (eg; -100 if they are owing $100.
- When an Account is 'PostPaid' (PlanCode = P0200) then the balance owing is positive (eg; 100 if they are owing $100)
- Some PrePaid accounts are owed money to and hence show balance as positive (eg;  50 would mean that we owe them $50)
- Some PostPaid Accounts are owed money too (as in they overpaid) and show balance as negative (eg; -50 would mean that we owe them $50)

I want to generate a report that shows all accounts that owe us $5 or more.

My code is wrong, but perhaps my logic is right?

```
SELECT A.[AccountId]
      ,A.[AccountNumber]
      ,CASE WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0100' THEN 'PrePaid'
        WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0200' THEN 'PostPaid'
       END PlanType
      ,CASE WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0100' THEN (Select ABS(CurrentBalance) FROM Account WHERE CurrentBalance < 0)
        WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0200' THEN (Select [CurrentBalance] FROM Account WHERE CurrentBalance > 0)
       END [CurrentBalance]

FROM [GEB_DWH].[dbo].[Account] A
INNER JOIN AccountPlan P ON A.AccountId = P.AccountId

WHERE A.CurrentBalance >= 5

ORDER BY CurrentBalance DESC
```

**EDIT:**
I've also tried:

```
SELECT A.[AccountId]
      ,A.[AccountNumber]
      ,CASE WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0100' THEN 'PrePaid'
        WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0200' THEN 'PostPaid'
       END PlanType
      ,ABS([CurrentBalance])[CurrentBalance]
      --,CASE WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0100' THEN (Select ABS(CurrentBalance) FROM Account WHERE CurrentBalance < 0)
        --WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0200' THEN (Select [CurrentBalance] FROM Account WHERE CurrentBalance > 0)
      -- END [CurrentBalance]

FROM [GEB_DWH].[dbo].[Account] A
INNER JOIN AccountPlan P ON A.AccountId = P.AccountId

WHERE ((P.PlanCode = 'P0100' AND (A.CurrentBalance)  < 0) OR (P.PlanCode = 'P0200' AND (A.CurrentBalance)  > 0))
  AND A.CurrentBalance > 5

ORDER BY CurrentBalance DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
WHERE (A.PlanCode = P0100 AND A.CurrentBalance >= 5) OR
      (A.PlanCode = P0200 AND A.CurrentBalance <= -5)
```

Comment: I had tried something similar earlier. But the records didn't match. It didn't show a Prepaid Account that owed a large sum of money. I also tried your code.

Comment: I'm sorry. I used your code and it worked. Had to make slight changes to suit my data.